# There is an error when I build the project

Tags: spring, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I have a project on Spring Framework

I get an error when I run mvn clean install -DskipTests:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project postcodeapp: Compilation failure
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Here are my mvn and java versions:

```
C:\Users\KazPost\Desktop\citypostkz\back-end>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11- 
10T22:41:47+06:00)
Maven home: C:\maven\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre
Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"

C:\Users\KazPost\Desktop\citypostkz\back-end>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_131

C:\Users\KazPost\Desktop\citypostkz\back-end>java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

maven-compiler-plugin in pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>testCompile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Here is the complete pom.xml and stackTrace: https://gist.github.com/Abdubek/741b4e543b2f376cb2bff42dba447a89

When I launch mvn clean install, the target folder is created and an error occurs, then when I launch locally, an error occurs

```
Error: java: java.lang.AssertionError
Error: java: at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:126)
```

if I delete the target folder and launch it locally once more, starts successfully. but after I launched mvn clean install does not start again.

Comment: Please replace the images with the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted this folder, which appeared in the process of wsimport and earned

com\microsoft\schemas_2003_10\serialization\ObjectFactory.java

During the search, I noticed in the console

/C:/Users/KazPost/Desktop/citypostkz/back-end/src/main/java/com/microsoft/schemas/_2003/_10/serialization/ObjectFactory.java:[29,8] duplicate class: com.microsoft.schemas._2003._10.serialization.ObjectFactory

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove as many `<version>` tag from your dependencies as possible. Spring Boot has managed versions for almost all of the popular packages. Let it manage the versions.

(Comment out all of the versions and put back only those where you got a maven error)

...

If it still doesn't run... call an exorcist. That pom is huge!

Comment: got a project recently, Before that, there were no problems with the versions, and I did not add any dependencies, everywhere they write what might be because of the version, are there any other options

Comment: Sorry, as I mentioned that pom is huge. There could be anything in it. I suggest to make a fresh workspace for it if you haven't done it yet.

Comment: I'm starting to rewrite it, only the old one is still supported